SAP Hybris ASM: Incorrect baseSite was set
I'm using a Customer Support Agent Employee account with the baseSite set to electronics/be/en, and I'm trying to impersonate a B2BCustomer account with baseSite set to apparel/es/en. I was able to impersonate the B2BCustomer account successfully.
However, when I check the Backoffice, under the impersonated B2BCustomer account cart section, I see two carts:

An extra cart with the previous baseSite (electronics/be/en).
A new active cart with the correct baseSite (apparel/es/en).

Question:

Is it possible to fix this so that only one cart with the correct baseSite (apparel/es/en) is generated? Or is this behavior part of the out-of-the-box (OOTB) functionality of SAP Hybris?

Before the URL changes to the correct baseSite, requests are sent.
We found API requests being called together with the OOTB /cart API. Is this behavior part of the out-of-the-box (OOTB) functionality of SAP Hybris?


Example API call:

/electronics-be/users

/electronics-be/cms/pages


